# Facebook login for devices is telling me "Blocking potential open redirect" after entering code

Tags: facebook-login

When I test entering the code that my device app shows me, Facebook displays that it's redirecting to my site but then displays the error: "Blocking potential open redirect". Why this error?

I've set up a URI redirect in the POST payload of:

https://test.songbookdb.com/facebookLoginPWA.html

My "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" in my account contains:

https://test.songbookdb.com/facebookLoginPWA.html

Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK are:

*.songbookdb.com

https://www.songbookdb.com/

https://test.songbookdb.com/

In the Domain Manager I have:

https://test.songbookdb.com/facebookLoginPWA.html

When I put https://test.songbookdb.com/facebookLoginPWA.html in the Check URI tester it says it's valid.

Thank you